# Storing RSA encrypted data as hexadecimal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, openssl

I am using `OpenSSL::PKey::RSA` to encrypt/decrypt a string of data using a private key. I am storing the encrypted data in a column in a table as a string.  I have gotten this implementation to work no problem using `Base64.encode64` and `Base64.decode64`.  However, I do not want to store the encrypted data as base 64, I would like to store it as hexadecimal in a string.

I'm currently using the following to store the encrypted data:

```
    encrypted_data = pk.private_encrypt(plain_data).unpack('H*').first
```

This results in `encrypted_Data` equaling a string like that bellow, which easily stores in my database.

```
   d70db8c36d6ccbadd1cca1263ff140df24e0112f636ac9ea92c28f27e443496c
```

My problem has come in the changing of this hexadecimal string back to the binary string that is needed to decrypt the data. I've tried several different approaches and none seem to work.

What is the best/easiest way to decrypt this hexadecimal string?

Answer (score 0):

The opposite of unpack is pack, which is what you're looking for to get this hex string back to binary. Like so:

```
[encrypted_data].pack('H*')
```

Pack is a function on array, not string, so be sure you're passing the same array that unpack('H*') results in or else the output will not be the same.

Comment: That seems to get it back to binary, but I don't think it's correct as I get this error: `OpenSSL::PKey::RSAError (padding check failed)`